# Clickonce Bootstrapping OpenXML 2.5

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, bootstrapper

I am using OpenXML to edit an XLSX file in my winform app.  Currently I am going to install OpenXML SDK 2.5 on each persons computer (which is only about 10 people).  But would like to bootstrap it to my ClickOnce deployment package so in future do not have to remember to install it separately.  Was wondering if anyone could guide me on how to do this?

Thank you,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

Just add DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to your ClickOnce package. This is the only dependency you need.

Regards,

Michael